# How to keep router's component state after routing to another component and got back to the first component

Tags: angular, user-interface, navigation, state, router

I'm working with Angular 2+ router.

I want to know if there is an easy way to setup the router so that once it loads a path and than moves to another path , it will save the first path state exectly like I'v left it.

An example for this is if we have an inner page with a video player.
If the user started the video and than the user wants to keep this video running (with a picture inside picture option) while moving to another path.
if the user moves to another path, the poped up video will continue to play, and if the user than goes back to the video page, it doesn't show the playing video, but instead it's initialize the page again (so he than has 2 running videos and he cannot turn off the first video).

Is there a way to keep the state which the user left the page?

Thanks!
Asaf

I'm expecting for a router's option for saving the state of the page and preventing page Init.